# Need inline_macro example and help about file location

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I like to add additional macros to *asciidoctor* for these types:

```
path:[some path value]
label:[some label text]
replace:[some value to become replaced by the user]
screen:[something the users sees on screen]
```

I mainly want to have it rendering some CSS classes while rendering to HTML5. I found several sources on how to write a macro for *asciidoctor*, but I do not get the point. Where to place or insert the ruby code and classes I write? Here is an example page I found: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/extensions/inline-macro-processor/

But I found no simple step-by-step information about where to place that?

Can someone tell me:

- In which file(s) shall I add my macro code?
- How to enable this in general for asciidoctor (so I can simply call it without the need to put it into the comandline call. Or do I have to register the macro in the call all the time?

I installed *asciidoctor* on Ubuntu 20.04 using **apt-get install asciidoctor**. Seems it works so far. But I found no files for the predefined macros *btn*, *kbd* and *menu*.

I'm a little lost here... Any help is appreciated.

PS. I know the syntax **[.label]#some label text#** to place CSS classes, but I want to have it generic and also usable for PDF generation later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different tries and research I finally found it to be easy. Just point asciidoctor to the file you want to include by using the -r comandline parameter:

```
asciidoctor -r ~/tools/asciidoctor_patch/include_asciidoc.rb
```

Sadly, the whole asciidoctor documentation names this parameter only "require" and does not even mention this to be used for extensions. I also found no source that mentions the use of -r for including the macros.